# How do I read the specifications on this DC contactor?

Tags: solenoid, contactor

This is a solenoid from an Italian made marine windlass.

Could you please help me understand the specifications written on it?

[image]

From what I know, the coil and connector is 12V because that is the voltage on the connections.

It was hooked up to an Optima Red Top battery for operations.

Comment: My Italian is limited to greetings and curse words suitable for a traffic jam, but I would interpret it as 12 V coil consuming an unknown amount of current with a 24 V rated contact which can take 180 A peak and 150 A continuous. Perhaps ask the manufacturer for a proper datasheet, preferably in English.

Comment: What does the 50% and 80% correspond to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some [technical data](http://www.imajteknik.com.tr/ravioli-t106-t156-T206-single-pole-dc-contactor) for a product that looks very similar in markings, save for the manufacturer or supplier logo which is a very Italian "Ravioli" rather than "Quick".

They claim it has a feature for quick drop-out and slow pull in for reversing applications. Also the coil appears to be intermittent duty only (80% duty cycle maximum) as marked on your unit- coil dissipation is a hefty 20W. Maximum on-time 15 minutes.

Your "Bobina" (coil) is 12V.

150A is the maximum continuous current (limited by heating) and it can break 720A.

"Class 300 - 50%" appears to mean maximum 300 operations per hour at 50% of rated current (not sure whether it's 50% of the 150A or the higher 180A intermittent rating).

As with all ratings, it's best to stay well away from the maximums  if you want long and reliable life span. No indication is given (that I can see) of the expected life in the webpage or pdf document that are linked. The 'mechanical life' of 2,000,000 operations is with zero load and is basically how long it takes to shake itself to death. Electrical life will likely be much, much fewer operations (could be as low as thousands or as high as 50,000 or 100,000) and very much dependent on load current and nature of the load.

Comment: I anchor 10-15 times a season. It will outlive me even with 5000 operations. Thank you for this wonderful breakdown! It really helps. 

I fid look at Ravioli spec sheet and the coil is 24V on that one but otherwise same thing I believe.

Comment: @Alexus You're welcome. The datasheet says 12 or 24V coil, so it's congruent.